# Chain Ladder Model: Unbiasedness of estimators for the variance parameters

Tags: soft-question, actuarial-science

I don't understand the equality of the middle term:

[image]

from page 40 of ["Wüthrich, M. V., & Merz, M. (2008). Stochastic claims reserving methods in insurance. John Wiley & Sons."](https://books.google.de/books?id=Wo5DIyzqaB4C&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q&f=false)
I see the first equality being this covariance, but how do we conclude the second equality being this facor times the variance?

Maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the second equality follows from the assumed independence of claim observations from different years.

First we plug in the definition of $\hat f=\frac{C_{0,j+1}+\dots+C_{I-j-1,j+1}}{C_{0,j}+\dots+C_{I-j-1,j}}$ which yields, by using the $\mathcal B_j$-measurability of $C_{0,j},\dots, C_{I-j-1,j}$,

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}\left(\frac{C_{i,j+1}}{C_{i,j}},\hat f\vert \mathcal B_j\right)&=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^{I-j-1}C_{i,j}} \operatorname{Cov}\left(\frac{C_{i,j+1}}{C_{i,j}},\sum_{k=0}^{I-j-1}C_{k,j+1}\vert \mathcal B_j\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^{I-j-1}C_{i,j}} \sum_{k=0}^{I-j-1} \operatorname{Cov}\left(\frac{C_{i,j+1}}{C_{i,j}},C_{k,j}\vert \mathcal B_j\right)
\end{align*}

Next, insert $1=\frac{C_{i,j}}{C_{i,j}}$ and use independence (see beginning), by which all cov-terms but one are vanishing:

$$
=  \frac{C_{i,j}}{\sum_{i=0}^{I-j-1}C_{i,j}}\operatorname{Cov}\left(\frac{C_{i,j+1}}{C_{i,j}}, \frac{C_{i,j+1}}{C_{i,j}}\vert \mathcal B_j\right)
$$